# how to go to next line if match is found and again check for the word and print the count of that word in the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find word count by find a match line if match is found go to next line and count the word in that line

```
id = open('id.txt','r')
ids = id.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(ids) - 1, 1):
    actual_id = ids[i]
    print(actual_id)
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(r'\{actual_id}\|RQ', line):
                next_line = line.next()
                solution_count = line.count('Solution')
                 print("The solution count is " + str(solution_count))
```

**Sample.txt** text file:

```
[07-12-2022 13:27:45.728|Info|0189B31C|RQ]
<ServiceRQ><SaleInfo><CityCode Solution=1>BLQ</CityCode><CountryCode Solution=2>NL</CountryCode><CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode><Channel>ICI</Channel></ServiceRQ>

[07-12-2022 13:27:45.744|Info|0189B31D|RQ]
<ServiceRQ><SaleInfo><CityCode Solution=1>BLQ</CityCode><CountryCode>NL</CountryCode><CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode><Channel>ICI</Channel></ServiceRQ>
```

**0189B31C**

**0189B31D**

These are unique id's which are store in different text file I am trying to read the 1st id from text file and match that id in Sample.txt and if match is found go to next line and count the number of **Solution** words and print. Please also help me with regex I want to match **{Id from text file}|RQ** to find the match in line.
Please can someone help me for find the code I am little confused.

Comment: `line.next()` should be `next(f)`

Comment: You never use `next_line`.

Comment: I changed but not getting the solution count.

Comment: Shouldn't `line.count` be `next_line.count`?

Comment: Please can you suggest me the regex to find the match {alphanumeric}|RQ  if its true then go to next line and print the count of word 'Solution' in that line

Comment: You need to use an f-string to substitute the variable.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use an f-string to substitute `actual_id` into the regexp.
- Put `|` before `{actual_id}` so it won't match a partial string.
- Use `f.readline()` to read the next line, not `line.next()`
- Count the words in `next_line`, not `line`.

```
id = open('id.txt','r')
ids = id.readlines()
for actual_id in ids[:-1]
    print(actual_id)
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(rf'\|{actual_id}\|RQ', line):
                next_line = f.readline()
                solution_count = next_line.count('Solution')
                print(f"The solution count is {solution_count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

- `re.search()` doesn't return a boolean value. It returns a `re.Match` object, if a match is found, and `None` if not. So your check should be `if re.search(...) is not None`
- Your `actual_id` variable isn't formatted into your regex string. Use `rf"..."` as suggested by @Barmar.
- If your 'sample.txt' is the same file for each iteration of the outer look, you probably just want to read it once and store it as list of strings, since reading a file is slow and reading the same file again and again has no point.
- The inner loop is more likely a case for a while loop, since a loop that eats sometimes two and times one line of an iterator/file can be confusing, and `readline()` won't help you, if you use my hint of reading `sample.txt` only once. The body of your outer loop could be

```
it = iter(samples)
try:
    line = next(it)
    while True:
        if ...:
            solution_count = next(it).count("solution")
            ...
        line = next(it)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```